# Add object to array list

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I try add object to ArrayList and got error:
Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   Voiting.addCandidate2(Voiting.java:29) at Main.main(Main.java:11)

```
  public ArrayList<Candidate> candidates;
  public void addCandidate2(String CandidateName){
        Candidate candidate=new Candidate(CandidateName);
        candidates.add(candidate); //нужен конструктор списка кандидатов
    }
```

Constructor Voiting:

```
public void Voiting(){
        candidates=new ArrayList<Candidate>();

    }
```

In main class:

```
Voiting voiting=new Voiting();
            voiting.setTitle("Vibor 2018");
            voiting.addCandidate2("Candidate1");
```

Comment: This: `public void Voiting(){` is not a constructor as it has a `void` return type. Get rid of the `void`! It should instead be: `public Voiting(){`. This is why it is not being called, and why your ArrayList remains null.

Comment: Please have a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694833/java-constructor-not-compiling-properly) for more on this.